# Scala query type to Boolean type

Tags: scala, boolean, slick

I imported the slick library and using it to make a table and trying to do this

```
val q = notes.filter(_.accessId === userId).run
```

notes is a TableQuery (imported from slick) of a Table I created.
I want to do something like

```
if (q.exists()) do something
```

but since q is a result of query, q.exists() doesn't really work.
How do I change it to a boolean type?

Answer (score 0):

```
q.headOption.foreach { _ =>
 //do something
}
```

or

```
if(!q.isEmpty()) {
  //do something
}
```